# four buttons from one button,depending on click location

Tags: java, android, xml

Screen shot:
[image]

I'm turning this Nokia phone into an android app(when you open the app the app shows the phone and you can do whatever you want with the phone,move around,send messages, etc...)

I cut each button with Photoshop and then placed them in the layout and ended up with this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/debug"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="not" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="74dp"
    android:layout_y="1dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/background" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lrb"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_x="87dp"
    android:layout_y="265dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/lrb" />
...
...
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The problem I'm having is with the button in the middle(the squared big one)
if i cut the button and place it in the layout, when the user clicks it i won't know if he clicked the right side of this button,or the left,or the upper, or the down.
and cutting it into four will lead to it being four separated imageviews which would give a horrible look

sorry for my English

Comment: I think you will require five images for the center big  button, one big center image for selecting, four side images for up,down,left and right direction. This will do...

Comment: how will i connect them so that they look one